# Force embedded youtube video autoplay?

Tags: video, youtube, autoplay, autorun

I know that we can autoplay the embed youtube video by adding the 'autoplay=1' parameter,

so if the embed link is like this

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/sorpTOyJXf8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

then the with autoplay would look like this

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/sorpTOyJXf8?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

but my concern is I have embedded quite a few youtube links in my site, it woulb be tedious to update the code one by one within the CMS, is there a javascript function that will enable youtube to autoplay globally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple solution. See the comments in the code for details on how it works:

```
//select the first iframe that has a src that links to youtube
var firstIframe = document.querySelector('iframe[src^="//www.youtube"]');

//get the current source
var src = firstIframe.src;

//update the src with "autoplay=1"
var newSrc = src+'?autoplay=1';

//change iframe's src
firstIframe.src = newSrc;
```

**[Live demo (click).](http://plnkr.co/edit/Bfu2m8dt5SPVm4OMoQIE?p=preview)**

Comment: This still pauses 2018+.